# Awesome nested set - how can I get a statement of any subtree?

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, tree, nested-sets

I am a newbie and I am playing with this gem. I have in database a tree structure. But now I am struggling with a way, how to get a statement of items for example on the first level... or the count items on the first or second level...

Could anyone help me please with this problem?
I found at GitHub this loop for a statement of items:

```
Category.each_with_level(Category.root.self_and_descendants) do |category, level|
  ...
end
```

But I still don't know, how to use it... I'll be glad for every hint!

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through all the categories and count the items on level 1.

With in Rails console try the following:

```
count = 0
Category.each_with_level(Category.all) do |account, level|
    count += 1 if level == 1
end
puts count
```

And to print the items you could try this:

```
Category.each_with_level(Category.all) do |account, level|
    puts "#{level} - #{category.name}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add the optional `depth` field, you can get the results in this manner:

```
count = Category.where(depth: 1).count
```